# Microsecond discrepancy between Django and Python

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I use a datetime property as part of a dynamic form's controls naming convention. I noticed that Python microseconds in a DateTime property are always 6 characters in length even if the first character is a 0. On my Django form though, the Django microseconds drops the leading 0.

Here is my Django:

```
name="foo-{{datecreated|date:'Y-m-d H:i:s.u}}"
```

Which creates:

```
name="foo-2013-11-15 15:41:33.40350"
```

Here is my Python (in a data model in appengine):

```
datecreated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

Which results in:

```
datecreated: 2013-11-15 15:41:33.040350
```

I do not see this mentioned in the Django or Python documentation. Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Based on the very helpful suggestions below I have confirmed the problem is in fact that the current supported version of Django in App Engine has a bug. Regarding a workaround until Django 1.6 is supported, this is what I was thinking of doing.  Basically checking the length of the microsecond string in Django and concatenating a leading 0 if necessary. Is there some disadvantage Im missing?

```
{%if datecreated|date:'u'|length == 6 %}render control name as above 
{% else %} 
<input type="radio" name="foo-{{datecreated|date:'Y-m-d H:i:s'}}{{datecreated|date:'.0u'}}"
```

Comment: I would personally consider this a bug in Django even though it is technically the correct number of microseconds, since you probably can't format the date correctly using it.

Comment: @Tim, do you have any ideas on how to address it?

Comment: What version of Django are you using?  Is it the most current ?

Comment: @techkilljoy unfortunately I have litte experience with Django and from the look of it, I don't really see how to change anything about it since it is a format string. You could fetch the first part in a string, fetch the microseconds in another, and pad it to 6 places yourself. But I have no Idea how to shoehorn that into a template. This is really something that the format string should do itself, so I would look in the bug repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, and the link to the php reference, I think this is happening:

- Django notes that "These format characters are not used in Django outside of templates. They were designed to be compatible with PHP to ease transitioning for designers" ( as @Leonardo.Z mentioned )  ]
- looking at the Django Docs for the date templating format [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date] , most items specifically mention whether or not there are leading zeroes
- microseconds merely states `000000 to 999999`
- looking at the php docs [http://bd1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php] , most things explicitly state with/without leading zeroes
- php states : `Microseconds (added in PHP 5.2.2). Note that date() will always generate 000000 since it takes an integer parameter, whereas DateTime::format() does support microseconds. Example: 654321`

So this basically looks to me like someone isn't zero-padding the template strings, although they should, because the original docs the function was written to be in compliance with were bad.

Let's look at the source for `microseconds`:

Django date parsing looks to be right  : https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/dateparse.py

I imagine this is the date writing tag : https://github.com/django/django/blob/c347f78cc1b2a06958f692f0622deceac534dc6b/django/utils/dateformat.py#L173-L175

and look, it's zero-padding the date in there.

So let's look at the history of the file...

zeropadding was introduced in this commit: https://github.com/django/django/commit/822cfce3df53301d9f9f4c14bd8a0cb2a1956e2e

That commit is over a year old, and part of 1.6c1 , the release candidate, which predates the current actual django production release.

**tldr; you have an old version of django with a known bug.  update django.**

Comment: Great in depth analysis of exactly what I suspected but had too little knowledge to research myself. :)

Comment: it takes a while.  eventually you understand where/how to start looking.

Comment: @Jonathan, thank you. That makes perfect sense and Im glad to see it has been addressed. Since Im using App Engine here and it still seems that Django 1.4 is the most current version, how would you suggest I go about addressing this in the interim?

Comment: You should be able to monkeypatch this.  I haven't used Django in a while, so I'm not sure where the best place to handle this would be ( a search on StackOverflow should answer that though).  If you're unfamiliar with MonkeyPatching, you basically just copy/paste the new (fixed) function from the current version into your app, and have your app inject override of the class method in the 1.4 version  with your fixed function.

Comment: Thanks.  Ill look into that. Do you think that is a better solution that handling it in Django as I mention in the edit to my original post?

Comment: In this case, I think it comes down to personal preference.  In order to backport the fix, you only need to monkeypatch a single classmethod - and it's a pretty simple one... so it shouldn't be messy.  By going that route, you won't have to worry about updating the templates once you can finally upgrade django.  but monkeypatching is still monkeypatching and many people don't like it ( myself included ). i might prefer updating the template or creating a custom widget/function -- but also implementing it with a docstring/comment identifying it as a fix and noting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) mentioned it.

> **date**
>
> Formats a date according to the given format.
>
> Uses a similar format as PHP’s date() function (http://php.net/date)
>   with some differences.

These format characters are not used in Django outside of templates. **They were designed to be compatible with PHP to ease transitioning for designers.**

Besides that, I think you might confused date/datetime objects with their string representings.

What you said `Here is my Django:` actually is `in Django templates`. Outside of templates, in views and models, date/datetime objects are same with those in non-django projects.

What you said `Here is my Python`, actually is in `Google Appengine ndb DateTimeProperty`.

Python's official datetime string representing format([strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)) does not include microsecond., I think that's one of the reason why django choose to use PHP's.

Comment: thanks for the background but Im most interested in what might be a common way others handle this situation. The Django documentation, which I read before posting just says microseconds range from 000000 to 999999 but fails to mention the dropping of the leading 0 if present. Any workaround would be appreciated.